# Remove text from a column with column image r markdown

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse, kableextra

I'm generating a document with pdf output using rmarkdown. This document contains a column where I am inserting images. The image is inserted correctly, but it comes with the value described in the dataframe.

How do I remove this name (teste.png, assinatura.png), leaving only the image?

[image]

##### Render.R

```r
dados = read.xlsx(“C:\Users\RibeiroF\OneDrive - xxx\Francisco\Área de Trabalho\Atividades\Agro\Coc Agro\dados.xlsx”)

    purrr::walk(
        .x = dados$amostras,
        ~ rmarkdown::render(
        input = “index.Rmd”,
        output_file = glue::glue(“Coc Agro - {.x}.pdf”),
        params = list(amostras = {.x})))
```

##### Index.Rmd

````
 ---
 title: "xxx - `r params$amostras` "
    author: "xxx"
    date: "2023-05-03"
    format:
      pdf:
        papersize: A3
        latex_engine: tinytex
        classoption: landscape
    execute:
      echo: false
      df-print: kable
    editor: visual
    params:
      amostras: amostras
    geometry: "a3paper,left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=4cm, landscape"
    header-includes:
      - \usepackage{booktabs}
      - \usepackage{longtable}
      - \usepackage{array}
      - \usepackage{multirow}
      - \usepackage{wrapfig}
      - \usepackage{float}
      - \usepackage{colortbl}
      - \usepackage{tabu}
      - \usepackage{threeparttable}
      - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
      - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
      - \usepackage{makecell}
      - \usepackage{xcolor}
      - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      - \usepackage{pdflscape}
      - \usepackage{lastpage}
      - \usepackage[labelformat = empty]{caption}
      - \pagestyle{fancy}
      - \fancyhf{}
      - \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}
      - \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{Bloco1 - Al, Ba, B, Cu, Fe, Si, Zn, Sb, As, Be, Cd, Pb, Co, Cr, Sn, Li, Mn, Ni, Hg, Mo, Ag, Se, Tl, Ti, U, V, Bloco2 - Ca, S, P, Mg, K, Na, Bloco3 - Tolueno, etilbenzeno, diclorometano, Bloco4 - Aldrin, Endrin, Dieldrin, HCHtotal, HCHgama/lindano, PCBs, Bloco5 - 2,4,5-triclorofenol e 2,4,6-triclorofenol, Bloco7 - As, Hg e Cr total, Bloco8 - Cr (III), Cr (VI), Bloco9 - As (III), As (V), Ácido monometilarsônico, Ácido dimetilarsínico e Arsenobetaína, Bloco9 - Atrazina e Clorpirifós}
      - \fancyfoot[C]{}
      - \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.25mm}

---

```{r carregando pacotes, include=FALSE}

library(rmarkdown)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(rmarkdown)
library(purrr)
library(tinytex)
library(pandoc)
library(janitor)
library(chron)

```

```{r dados, include=FALSE}

dados = read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\RibeiroF\\OneDrive - xxx\\Francisco\\Área de Trabalho\\Atividades\\Agro\\Coc Agro\\dados.xlsx")

    dados = dados %>%
      clean_names()%>%
      mutate(data = as.numeric(data),
             data = as.Date(data, format = "%d/%m/%Y", origin = "30/12/1899"),
             hora = as.numeric(hora),
             hora = as.times(hora, format = "h:m"))
```
                                          
|--------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------|
| Empresa contratante: xxx                                     | Gestores responsáveis: XXX |
| Empresa responsável pela coleta e execução das análises: xxx | Gestor responsavel:XXX     |

```{r tabelas, echo=FALSE}

    ponto = dados%>%
      dplyr::filter(amostras == params$amostras)%>%
      dplyr::select(amostras)%>%
      dplyr::distinct()%>%
      dplyr::mutate(ponto = "")%>%
      dplyr::mutate(ponto = str_extract(amostras, "[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{4}"))%>%
      dplyr::select(ponto)%>%
      pull

    amostra = dados%>%
      dplyr::filter(amostras == params$amostras)%>%
      dplyr::select(amostras)%>%
      dplyr::distinct()%>%
      pull

    tipo = dados%>%
      dplyr::filter(amostras == params$amostras)%>%
      dplyr::select(amostras)%>%
      dplyr::distinct()%>%
      dplyr::mutate(tipo = "")%>%
      dplyr::mutate(tipo = case_when(
        str_detect(amostras, "T0")~ "Simples",
        str_detect(amostras, "T1")~ "Simples",
        str_detect(amostras, "T2")~ "Simples",
        str_detect(amostras, "T3")~ "Simples",
        str_detect(amostras, "TE")~ "Composta"))%>%
      dplyr::select(tipo)%>%
      pull
    
    alimento = dados%>%
      dplyr::filter(amostras == params$amostras)%>%
      dplyr::select(amostras)%>%
      dplyr::distinct()%>%
      dplyr::mutate(alimento = "")%>%
      dplyr::mutate(alimento = case_when(
        str_detect(amostras, "FR01") ~ "Abacate",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR02") ~ "Abacaxi",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR03") ~ "Acerola",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR04") ~ "Banana",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR05") ~ "Cacau",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR06") ~ "Cana-de-açúcar",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR07") ~ "Coco-da-baía",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR08") ~ "Goiaba",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR09") ~ "Laranja",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR10") ~ "Limão",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR11") ~ "Mamão",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR12") ~ "Manga",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR13") ~ "Maracujá",
        str_detect(amostras, "FR14") ~ "Melancia",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE01") ~ "Abóbora",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE02") ~ "Abobrinha",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE03") ~ "Batata-inglesa",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE04") ~ "Batata-doce",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE05") ~ "Berinjela",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE06") ~ "Beterraba",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE07") ~ "Cenoura",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE08") ~ "Chuchu",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE09") ~ "Inhame",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE10") ~ "Jiló",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE11") ~ "Mandioca",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE12") ~ "Pepino",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE13") ~ "Pimentão",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE14") ~ "Quiabo",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE15") ~ "Tomate",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE16") ~ "Vagem",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE01") ~ "Alface",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE02") ~ "Almeirão",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE03") ~ "Couve",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE04") ~ "Mostarda",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE05") ~ "Repolho",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE06") ~ "Agriao",
        str_detect(amostras, "GR01") ~ "Café",
        str_detect(amostras, "GR02") ~ "Feijão",
        str_detect(amostras, "LT01") ~ "Vaca",
        str_detect(amostras, "LT02") ~ "Cabra",
        str_detect(amostras, "OV01") ~ "Galinha",
        str_detect(amostras, "ME01") ~ "Mel",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU01") ~ "Bovinos - Traseiro",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU01") ~ "Bovinos - Traseiro",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU02") ~ "Bovinos - Costela",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU02") ~ "Bovinos - Costela",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU03") ~ "Galinha - Coxa e sobrecoxa sem pele",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU04") ~ "Galinha - Sobrecoxa com pele",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU05") ~ "Suínos - Traseiro",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU05") ~ "Suínos - Traseiro",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU06") ~ "Suínos - Costela",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU06") ~ "Suínos - Costela",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI01") ~ "Coração de bovino",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI02") ~ "Fígado de bovino",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI03") ~ "Intestino de bovino",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI04") ~ "Coração de galinha",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI05") ~ "Fígado de galinha",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI06") ~ "Moela de galinha"))%>%
      dplyr::select(alimento)%>%
      pull
    
    grupo = dados%>%
      dplyr::filter(amostras == params$amostras)%>%
      dplyr::select(amostras)%>%
      dplyr::distinct()%>%
      dplyr::mutate(grupo = "")%>%
      dplyr::mutate(grupo = case_when(
        str_detect(amostras, "FR[0-9]{2}")~ "Fruto",
        str_detect(amostras, "GR[0-9]{2}")~ "Grão",
        str_detect(amostras, "LE[0-9]{2}")~ "Legume",
        str_detect(amostras, "LT[0-9]{2}")~ "Leite",
        str_detect(amostras, "ME[0-9]{2}")~ "Mel",
        str_detect(amostras, "MU[0-9]{2}")~ "Músculo",
        str_detect(amostras, "OV[0-9]{2}")~ "Ovo",
        str_detect(amostras, "VE[0-9]{2}")~ "Verdura",
        str_detect(amostras, "VI[0-9]{2}")~ "Viceras"))%>%
      dplyr::select(grupo)%>%
      pull
    
    tabela_1 = dados %>%
      dplyr::filter(amostras == params$amostras,
                    is.na(custodia),
                    etapa %in% c("Coleta dos produtos agropecuarios",
                                 "Transporte dos produtos agropecuarios para a base de apoio",
                                 "Recebimento e armazenamento dos produtos agropecuarios na base de apoio",
                                 "Transporte dos produtos agropecuarios entre bases de apoio",
                                 "Recebimento e armazenamento dos produtos agropecuarios entre bases de apoio"))%>%
      dplyr::mutate(outras_informacoes = case_when(str_detect(amostras, "LE15")~ "Teste tomate",
                                                   str_detect(amostras, "FR05")~ "Teste cacau"))%>%
      dplyr::mutate(amostras = str_extract(amostras, "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}"))%>%
      dplyr::select(-c(substancia, custodia))
    
    nomes_colunas_tabela_1 = c("Etapa",
                               "Código produto agropecuário",
                               "Data",
                               "Hora",
                               "Responsável",
                               "Assinatura",
                               "Código Equipamento",
                               "Temperatura Mínima",
                               "Temperatura Máxima",
                               "Temperatura entrega/recebimento",
                               "Outras Informações")

```

Informações da Amostra

Amostra: `r amostra`
Ponto: `r ponto`
Tipo: `r tipo`
Alimento: `r alimento`
Grupo: `r grupo`

```{r tabela_1, echo=FALSE, include=F, fig.pos='H'}

    tabela_1  = kableExtra::kbl (tabela_1, caption = "Atividades de campo", booktabs = T, longtable = T, 
                                 col.names = nomes_colunas_tabela_1, align = "c")%>%
      kable_styling(font_size = 10, latex_options = c("repeat_header", "HOLD_position"), position = "center")%>%
      column_spec (1, bold = T, width = "4cm")%>%
      column_spec (6, width = "4cm", image = spec_image(tabela_1$assinatura, 150, 150))

```

`r tabela_1`
````